# Is there a way to submit an iOS app to the App Store when you get "The resource can not be found" error but no details?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Usually the App Store lists specific items that need fixing. However this error does not give any actions and there appears to be no way to remove this specific version.

I have screenshots, text fields, etc. required. There are no sections highlighted in red (like there usually are) and only the screenshots and (simple) whats new text has been changed since the last update, which went through to review fine.

No warnings or errors when uploading the binary in Xcode and the binary and screenshots have been uploaded multiple times with the same outcome.

Screenshot attached:
[image]

Comment: Since you've found an answer on your own, go ahead and accepts it (click the check mark next to it) so that it's clear that the question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out our issue was with a "appEncryptionDeclarations" key.

The error was returned from the API call to:
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/iris/v1/reviewSubmissionItems
(Returned a 409 response code)

Response json:

```
    {
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "...",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "STATE_ERROR.ENTITY_STATE_INVALID",
    "title" : "appStoreVersions with id '...' is not in valid state.",
    "detail" : "This resource cannot be reviewed, please check associated errors to see why.",
    "meta" : {
      "associatedErrors" : {
        "/v1/appEncryptionDeclarations/" : [ {
          "id" : "...",
          "status" : "404",
          "code" : "NOT_FOUND",
          "title" : "The specified resource does not exist",
          "detail" : "There is no resource of type 'appEncryptionDeclarations' with id 'null'"
        } ]
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

The App Store UI was not showing the error or giving any detail to us.

We resolved by deleting the key `ITSEncryptionExportComplianceCode` and `ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption` from the info plist file. Uploading a new binary (it confirmed the keys were missing). Add back in with the same values as before and re-upload the binary.

Then into the review queue without problem. Hope this helps someone else.